# How do I do nested parenthesis in antlr4?

Tags: nested, grammar, dsl, antlr4, nested-lists

I have the following grammar

```
query
    : unquoted_str+
    | '(' query ')'
    ;

unquoted_str
    : UNQUOTED_STR
    ;

UNQUOTED_STR
    : [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_-]*
    ;
WS
    :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
    ;
```

I want to be able to execute the following query:

> `abc (def (hij))`

But I keep getting the error:

```
line 1:4 extraneous input '(' expecting {<EOF>, UNQUOTED_STR}
line 1:8 extraneous input ')' expecting {<EOF>, UNQUOTED_STR}
```

Have tried to fix the issue by adding EOF to various places but to no avail.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your grammar a query is either:

- A sequence of one or more `unquoted_str`s, or
- an <kbd>(</kbd>, a `query`, and a <kbd>)</kbd>

Is `abc (def)` a `query`?

No. `(def)` is not an `unquoted_str`, so the first option doesn't apply. And `abc` does not start with an <kbd>(</kbd>, so the second option doesn't apply either. Since those are the only two options, we conclude that it is not. And so did Antlr; it is telling you that after it sees an `unquoted_str` (`abc`), it expects to see another one, or the end of input.

From you example, I suppose you might have meant that a query is one or more query elements where a query element is either a single `unquoted_str` or a parenthesized `query`. If that's what you meant, you should change your grammar to specify that.

Comment: That was it, thanks!  Just changed query to the following: query : (unquoted_str|'(' query ')')+;